# Translate out of the box component labels

Tags: translation, outofbox

I'm using the Top Article by Topic component provided by salesforce. (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_top_article_by_topic.htm&type=5)

I would like to add translations to the View all button at the bottom of the component, but I can't figure it out how.

Is there a solution for this?